# Minimum number of money to make each element in list greater than or equal to 0?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, optimization

Given list with positive and negative integers.We have to make each element greater than or equal to zero.There are two types of moves first increase all elements by 1 requires P unit of money, second increase a particular element by 1 requires 1 unit of money.

Find the minimum unit of money to make all elements greater than or equal to zero.

Integers limit $(-10)^9$ to $10^9$

List length - $10^5$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just find the most negative element and increase all elements by $1$ enough times to get to zero?  This is the minimum number of steps, though there may be other equally short paths.

Added: now that we are given that increasing all elements costs $P$, we are better off increasing all as long as there are more than $P$ that are negative.  When exactly $P$ are negative, it is a breakeven, and when less are negative it is cheaper to increase them individually.  So the new algorithm is: 1)find the $P^{\text{th}}$ most negative element. 2)increase all until it is zero 3)increase all the remaining negative ones individually until they reach zero.

Comment: But the OP wanted to minimize the *cost* of getting all the numbers to be nonnegative. With the list $\langle\,-7, -2, -1\,\rangle$, increasing all would cost $7P$, but increasing each individually would cost $7+2+1$ so if $P\le 10/7$ your technique would be cheapest, but if $P>10/7$ the second would be cheaper. It gets even more complicated....

Comment: @RickDecker:  That wasn't part of the question when I answered it.  I'll update.

Comment: i am sorry for updating the question  after your answer Ross